# connect access database to html file

Tags: html, ms-access

I am trying to connect Html file to access database . i already created html file that contain all field information but i don't know how to connect these file to access database is their any way to do these.

Comment: What scripting language are you using to process the data? E.g. ASP.NET, JS, PHP, etc...

Comment: HTML is a markup language. You need a programming language to do that.

Answer (score 0):

bottom line is you can't 
details

imagine a national phone book database with names and phone numbers of everyone in the country

now HTML runs on a browser so to actually connect and use the database you have to download the database to the client machine (the whole thing) and then start writing some script (possibly js) to connect to the database and use it.

though there's so many things which are wrong about what i wrote but that summs it up

NOW how do they do it
you use some kind of a server  language like asp,php, python, ruby.... to run on the server connect to the database then generate an html file and send (just the needed data) that to the client's browser to view.